# Lottery contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

when I try to run the pickWinner function of my lottery contract, I get such an error. With getPlayers, I can add players and query with players. The address of the manager is visible, but I cannot run the pickWinner function by selecting the address of the manager. What could be the reason?

[image: 1]

I did try different values but i did not find solution

Comment: gas estimation errors are not always gas related error. post the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the code so we can figure out the answer, but I can see your `pickWinner` function has a `restricted` modifier. If the modifier is preventing the transaction from executing, then the client (remix, metamask, etc) won't be able to estimate the gas.